# I have file called songs and i'm trying to find the longest and shortest song name using AWK

Tags: unix, find, awk, find-in-files

```
RANK  NAME                    BAND  YEAR   GENERE  DOMESTIC/INTERNATIONAL 

206:Reach Out, I'll Be There:The Four Tops:1978:Pop:3/2
207:Bye Bye Love:The Everly Brothers:1950:Classic:3/2
208:Gloria:Them:1965:Classic:1/1
209:In My Room:The Beach Boys:1985:Classic:5/7
210:96 Tears:? & the Mysterians:1964:Classic:20/15
211:Caroline, No:The Beach Boys:1975:Classic:5/7
212:1999:Prince:1958:Classic:5/7
213:Your Cheatin' Heart:Hank Williams:1988:Soul:7/6
214:Rockin' in the Free World:Neil Young:1960:Pop:5/7
215:Sh-Boom:The Chords:1967:Alternative:3/2
216:Do You Believe in Magic:The Lovin' Spoonful:1988:Classic
217:Jolene:Dolly Parton:1998:Classic:7/6
218:Boom Boom:John Lee Hooker:1966:Classic:7/6
```

Comment: this is the file songs, and i tried 
awk 'BEGIN {max = 0} {if ($2>max) max=$2} END {print max}' songs 
and I couldn't write this code without script in the korn shell because it's long if(NR==1){max=min=$2} else{l=length($2) max=(l>length(max))?$2:max min (l<length(min))?$2:min}}
END{print max print min}' songs
In college we didn't cover much about awk because of the time and the above codes return errors

Comment: You can't put nicely formatted code in comments. Feel free to edit your answer, and click the "?" on the top right of the edit text area for formatting help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the header is not part of the file:

```
awk -F: '
    NR == 1 {max=$2; min=$2; next} 
    length($2) > length(max) {max=$2} 
    length($2) < length(min) {min=$2} 
    END {print "longest=" max; print "shortest=" min}
' songs
```

```
longest=Rockin' in the Free World
shortest=1999
```